# Jquery input multiple base on another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna try multiplying input text base on another input. Example if i'm input value 3, it gonna show 3 input text, or if i'm input 4 is gonna show 4 input text. But my problem is every time i'm change input value it not resetting but still adding input.
Here my code on jquery :

```js
$("#numcolor").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
  var num = parseInt($('#numcolor').val(), 10);
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    var $div = $('#colorinput');
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      $div.append('<input type="text" class="colortext" />');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
# input:<input id="numcolor">
<div id="colorinput"></div>
```

```
$("#numcolor").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
  var num = parseInt($('#numcolor').val(), 10);
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    var $div = $('#colorinput');
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      $div.append('<input type="text" class="colortext" />');
    }
  }
});
```

Here my demo on http://jsfiddle.net/xmzopnLa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by resetting the HTML content inside the $div element to ("") before the loop is called again, like this:

```js
$( "#numcolor" ).bind("keyup change", function(e) {
 var num = parseInt($('#numcolor').val(), 10);
 if (!isNaN(num)){
  var $div = $('#colorinput');
    $div.html("");
  for(var i=0;i< num;i++) {
   $div.append('<input type="text" class="colortext" />');
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Number of inputs :
<input id="numcolor" type="text" />
<div id="colorinput"></div>
```

Now remember that this would delete the input fields and re-apply them with the specified amount, so be cautious. You could hide or make the input field uneditable.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending new inputs on every event. You have to clear your container before appending inputs:

```
   $("#numcolor").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
       var num = parseInt($('#numcolor').val(), 10);
       if (!isNaN(num)) {
           var $div = $('#colorinput');
           $div.empty(); // clear container
           for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
               $div.append('<input type="text" class="colortext" />');
           }
       }
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

If u want to save values of previous inputs just check if it exist and delete the rest after:

```
$( "#numcolor" ).bind("keyup change", function(e) {
  var num = parseInt($('#numcolor').val(), 10);
  if (!isNaN(num)){
    var $div = $('#colorinput');

    for(var i=0;i< num;i++) {
      if(!$(".colortext")[i]) $div.append('<input type="text" class="colortext" />');
    }
    var temp=$(".colortext").length;
    for (var i=num;i<temp;i++){
      $($(".colortext")[$(".colortext").length-1]).remove();

    }

  }
```